# Disable radio button based on PHP function

Tags: php, database, radio-button

I want to call the javascript function based on the result coming from a PHP script.

```
if ($verify == 'Y' and $approve== 'Y' and $approve_2=='Y') { 
        $state = "disable";
    } else { 
        $state = "undisable"; 
    }
```

Below is my javascript function

```
function disable() {
                document.getElementById("approvedd1").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("approvedd2").disabled = true;
}

function undisable() {
                document.getElementById("approvedd1").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("approvedd2").disabled = false;
}

document.onreadystatechange = <?php echo $state; ?>()
```

This does not work. 
I want to call function that can disable radio button, when the page has loaded.

Comment: as a suggestion you can use $state flag variable directly in html.'<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" disabled="<?php echo $state?>"> Male'

Comment: already tried that too, and radio button still enable

Answer (score 0):

The current output of your java script will be

```
function disable() {
            document.getElementById("approvedd1").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("approvedd2").disabled = true;
}

function undisable() {
            document.getElementById("approvedd1").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("approvedd2").disabled = false;
}

document.onreadystatechange = disabled/undisabled()
```

**better you can try**

**php**

```
if ($verify == 'Y' and $approve== 'Y' and $approve_2=='Y') { 
    $state = "true";
} else { 
    $state = "false"; 
}
```

**Java Script**

```
 document.onreadystatechange = MyFun() {
    document.getElementById("approvedd1").disabled = <?php echo $state; ?>;
    document.getElementById("approvedd2").disabled = <?php echo $state; ?>;
 }
```